# Is it possible to convert SUSE Linux device drivers to Ubuntu's?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, hp

I have a "[HP ProBook 450 G1](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5405424)" netbook, for which there are some drivers in a [Linux section of its support page](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5405424&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D2020%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). All of the downloads there are marked to be for "SUSE Linux". So, my question is simple:

Is it possible to convert those SUSE Linux device drivers to be used in Ubuntu 14.04 and if it is, how?

Comment: Which of those drivers do you think are missing in Ubuntu? It is not so likely that drivers built for the Suse kernel last year will work with the kernel that Ubuntu is currently shipping in 14.04.

Comment: This one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1220146

Answer (score 1):

The description in the download table is wrong (probably, HP only wants to support one distribution), the drivers are just .tar files, i.e. archives which should work for all Linux distributions.

However, usually, there is no need to download any drivers from the manufacturer's webpage, since all drivers are either available out of the box or can be installed through the package management.

edit: Scratch it, HP indeed packed rpm packages into the archives. The second part is, however, still true, you should not need to install any drivers from HP's webpage.

Comment: If absolutely necessary, however, the .rpm packages could be converted to .deb using a tool called `alien`.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Suse driver is built for kernel 3.0.76. You need a driver that is built for the Ubuntu 14.04 kernel, which is currently at 3.13.0.

The Suse driver is based on [this github repository of a Chinese Canonical employee](https://github.com/anthonywong/mt7630), he says there *"The current status of the driver is it works under 3.5, and possibly fails to even compile in later version of kernels."* According to reports in [Launchpad bug #1220146](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146) that driver does not work with later kernels even if you do compile it.

From the [discussion on linux-kernel-wireless](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.wireless.general/124693) it appears that someone is planning to do the work to get this wireless device supported in the mainline kernel, but it has not been done yet.

Unless you are willing to help port or test the new driver that will be developed (see linux-kernel-wireless link), there is nothing you can do but wait.